# How do I insert a User Name info a path?

Tags: c#, string, path

So my goal is to put a **UserName** string into **the path users**.

```
Here = UserName

String UserName = Environment.UserName;
Path = @"C:\Users\ Here \AppData\Local\Secret\Secret";
```

Comment: Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For just concatenating an arbitrary string with a path, you could do:

```
var user = Environment.UserName;
var path = Path.Combine(Path.Combine(@"C:\Users", user), @"AppData\Local\Secret\Secret");
```

But, as you mentioned the `AppData` folder, you could be looking for some special folder in the windows structure; in that case, you should let the .NET framework do the magic by calling `Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder)`; in my box it returned the following values:

```
AdminTools            : C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Administrative Tools
ApplicationData       : C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming
CDBurning             : C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\Burn\Burn
CommonAdminTools      : C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Administrative Tools
CommonApplicationData : C:\ProgramData
CommonDesktopDirectory: C:\Users\Public\Desktop
CommonDocuments       : C:\Users\Public\Documents
CommonMusic           : C:\Users\Public\Music
CommonOemLinks        :
CommonPictures        : C:\Users\Public\Pictures
CommonProgramFiles    : C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files
CommonProgramFilesX86 : C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files
CommonPrograms        : C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs
CommonStartMenu       : C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu
CommonStartup         : C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup
CommonTemplates       : C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Templates
CommonVideos          : C:\Users\Public\Videos
Cookies               : C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\INetCookies
Desktop               : C:\Users\username\OneDrive\Desktop
DesktopDirectory      : C:\Users\username\OneDrive\Desktop
Favorites             : C:\Users\username\Favorites
Fonts                 : C:\WINDOWS\Fonts
History               : C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\History
InternetCache         : C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\INetCache
LocalApplicationData  : C:\Users\username\AppData\Local
LocalizedResources    :
MyComputer            :
MyDocuments           : C:\Users\username\OneDrive\Documentos
MyMusic               : C:\Users\username\Music
MyPictures            : C:\Users\username\OneDrive\Imagens
MyVideos              : C:\Users\username\Videos
NetworkShortcuts      : C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Network Shortcuts
MyDocuments           : C:\Users\username\OneDrive\Documentos
PrinterShortcuts      : C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Printer Shortcuts
ProgramFiles          : C:\Program Files (x86)
ProgramFilesX86       : C:\Program Files (x86)
Programs              : C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs
Recent                : C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Recent
Resources             : C:\WINDOWS\resources
SendTo                : C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\SendTo
StartMenu             : C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu
Startup               : C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup
System                : C:\WINDOWS\system32
SystemX86             : C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64
Templates             : C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Templates
UserProfile           : C:\Users\username
Windows               : C:\WINDOWS
```

If you need to do it by yourself:

```
foreach (var name in Enum.GetNames(typeof(Environment.SpecialFolder)).OrderBy(item => item))
{
    var item = Enum.Parse(typeof(Environment.SpecialFolder), name);
    var path = Environment.GetFolderPath((Environment.SpecialFolder)item);
    Console.WriteLine($"{item}: {path}");
}
```

Anyways, in your concrete case you should go with:

```
var secret = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(
    Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData), @"Secret\Secret");
```

Answer (score 0):

Taking what @Bhushan has put plus using string interpolation you can do something like

```
String UserName = Environment.UserName;
var Path = $@"C:\Users\{UserName}\AppData\Local\Secret\Secret";
```